# More efficient way possible?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this piece of code, however I think it can be written more efficient.

```
this.selectedDub = this.items.filter(item =>
      item.fields.dub_Key.value === value);

this.selectedDubContent = this.selectedDub[0].fields as Dub;
this.selectedDubRendering = this.selectedDub[0] as TypedComponentRendering<Dub>;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This isn't specific enough to be answerable here.  At a minimum, we would need your definition of "logical" in this context.  Read [ask].

Comment: You could use the find method instead of the filter method

Comment: Can you share a playground link with more code?

Comment: Same comment for "efficient."  What is your definition?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I feel like this could be written smarter/shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.selectedDubRendering = this.items.find(item =>
      item.fields.dub_Key.value === value) as TypedComponentRendering<Dub>;

this.selectedDubContent = this.selectedDubRendering?.fields ?? undefined;
```

You could check out the TypeScript find method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

> The find() method returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.